# Serialized FosuserBundle Roles prevent me to login with user account created using my java app

Tags: java, php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I am trying to create a Desktop java application, that shares the same database as my website (created using `Symfony 3` framework).

The problem is when i create a user using my Java app, when i login with this user through `FosuserBundle` in my website, i face this exception:

`Could not convert database value "" to Doctrine Type array.`

i tried to manually set the user role to a serialized string in my java code:

```
usr.setRole("a:1:{i:0;s:10:\"ROLE_INDIV\";}");
```

but i face the same exception, Doctrine is failing to unserialize it.

Comment: are you sure it's the 'role' which cannot be unserialized? have you tried a simple: `a:0:{}` just to make sure it's getting unserialized?

Comment: tried it, and still not working!